# Resetting odometry(pose) information

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am conducting an experiment that compares different navigation algorithms for a short distance (<4~5m) using a turtlebot, by plotting the sequences of locations contained in the odom messages. Since I am concerned with only short distances, I am not willing to use any localization to estimate the precise pose(location) of the robot.

The problem is that because I am relying only on odometry information (i.e. how much wheels have turned) to estimate the pose of the robot, odometry messages contain different pose information even for a same location. As a result, everytime I switch between navigation algorithms I need to turn off and turn on the turtlebot package in order to start at (0,0).

Is there a way to manually set the pose of the robot without turning on and off the turtlebot package? I am using turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62566/resetting-odometry(pose)-information/) by [bkim](https://answers.ros.org/users/3018/bkim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2013-05-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe that the turtlebot driver supports re-initializing odometry. I haven't used the kobuki driver, but if you have a turtlebot 2.0 then give it a shot. It has a reset_odometry feature as described [here](http://ros.org/wiki/kobuki_node?distro=groovy).

In general, you can solve this problem by writing a node that subscribes odom messages and republishes them for plotting. You can then add a service to this node that zeros out the values.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2013-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lucile](https://answers.ros.org/users/4897/lucile/) on 2013-05-28**:
Hi ! I tried to use that reset_odometry that you linked (I am trying to do the same thing as bkim, except that I try to do it for a Turtlebot2), it doesn't seem to work. Maybe it hasn't been implemented yet ?

**Comment by [benabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2641/benabruzzo/) on 2014-02-17**:
Has there been any update to this?  I have a similar desire.